# Please help i have get following error,when i try to integrate twitter in my app

Tags: android, twitter

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.brickred.socialauth.SocialAuthManager
                                                                          at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter.authorize(SocialAuthAdapter.java:544)
                                                                          at com.example.koolkrew.MainActivity.initSocialAdapter(MainActivity.java:90)
                                                                          at com.example.koolkrew.MainActivity.bindWidgetEvents(MainActivity.java:55)
                                                                          at com.example.koolkrew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Use fabric for twitter login,

Answer (score 0):

Download  `socialauth-android.jar`  from following link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/socialauth/socialauth-android.jar.zip

And if still getting the same error then You just need to define a new activity in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Put the below code inside  ---- tag of your manifest file.

```
<uses-library android:name="org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter" />
```